# NSNumberFormatter glitch

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, nsnumberformatter

I have a strange problem. It only seems to present on a tester's iPhone 5s.
It works correctly on an iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus, all running the latest iOS (8.3).

This is the code

```
-(NSString *) commaString:(double)number
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:9];
    NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: number]];

    return numberAsString;
}
```

The application is a calculator and is usually presenting correctly like this

It is usually showing correctly like this
[image]
but on this iPhone 5s it is showing like this
[image]

I thought the `setMaximumSignificantDigits` would have nipped this in the bud, but it's still showing the same. Could this be some strange localisation thing? I don't think it is as his iPhone 6 it is showing correctly also.
Thanks
Luke

Comment: Also, what is the locale settings for each device?

Comment: Looks like the device for the 2nd image has its locale set differently that for the 1st device (e.g., India on the 2nd device).

Comment: What is your goal? Is the second version not appropriate for the user's locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to simply have commas every three characters, all you need to do is:

```
    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

    NSNumber * numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:currentTextWithoutCommas];
    NSString * formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberFromString];
```

If you're finding that there's an issue with localizing the formatter, then set `secondaryGroupingSize` to 3. As written in the docs for `NSNumberFormatter`:

> Some locales allow the specification of another grouping size for larger numbers. For example, some locales may represent a number such as 61, 242, 378.46 (as in the United States) as 6,12,42,378.46. In this case, the secondary grouping size (covering the groups of digits furthest from the decimal point) is 2.

Also, you can check out [Formatting Numbers](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/formatting-numbers-nsnumberformatter-examples.html) on iOSDeveloperTips for a brief, high-level overview.

Comment: the question brings up the idea about localization, which does explain the number being seen on the 5s. I don't know of how the 5s would be intrinsically different to cause this number to be displayed differently from a 6 or 6+ @rmaddy

Comment: Hmmm I thought the problem was the two numbers being different, not just the formatting. Maybe not.

Comment: Sorry. The problem is the comma separation, not the actual numbers.

Comment: on your device, @mylogon, can you reproduce the problem your tester has by changing your localization (I guess India is viable judging by someone else's comments)? and if so, does changing the `secondaryGroupingSize` resolve?

Comment: I have changed it and submitted. I will return once I receive feedback from the tester.  Thanks

Comment: This was successful, even though their phone did not have any Indian settings enabled, apparently. I am also told that, in India, commas only separate two digits once you reach 1 million - 1,000,000 is written as 10,00,000 and read as 10 lakhs. This was occurring at 1,000 and beyond.

Comment: glad to hear! good to know that comma rule, did not know that